# How to assign each button to open a pdf file from assets folder

Tags: java, android, android-layout, button

Hi there please my goal is to create an application with five buttons to open five book pdf by each one of them open an different activity .

**MainActivity class**:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.btn1:
            x=1;
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Pdf_Activity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            break;
        case R.id.btn2:
            x=2;
            Intent i2=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Pdf_Activity.class);
            startActivity(i2);
            break;
        case R.id.btn3:
            x=3;
            Intent i3=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Pdf_Activity.class);
            startActivity(i3);
            break;
        case R.id.btn4:
            x=4;
            Intent i4=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Pdf_Activity.class);
            startActivity(i4);
            break;
        case R.id.btn5:
            x=5;
            Intent i5=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Pdf_Activity.class);
            startActivity(i5);
            break;
            default:
                break;
    }
```

**I want to open a pdf file within buttons
and this is "pdf_Activity" :**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_pdf);
   switch (main.x)
   {
       case (1):
           pdf1=(PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdf1);
           pdf1.fromAsset("insani.pdf").load();
           break;
       case (2):
           pdf2=(PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdf2);
           pdf2.fromAsset("kawniya.pdf").load();
           break;
       case (3):
           pdf3=(PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdf3);
           pdf3.fromAsset("3ilm.pdf").load();
           break;
       case (4):
           pdf4=(PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdf4);
           pdf4.fromAsset("9iyam.pdf").load();
           break;
       case (5):
           pdf5=(PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdf5);
           pdf5.fromAsset("a5la9.pdf").load();
           break;
           default:
               break;
   }
```

**I think there are some problems in these two code . please help**

Comment: What's not working? is it not doing anything?

Comment: yes,pdf files don't open

Comment: What is `PDFView`, is that a library you included?

Comment: yes :import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView;

Comment: the problem is not there because the code works correctly if I use one button

Comment: in the `onCreate` of `pdf_Activity` what is the value of main.x? Try `System.out.println(Integer.toString(main.x));`

Comment: You only need to assign one Intent variable before the switch... What is the purpose of `x`, though?

Comment: can't see it !!

Comment: x to stock the choice after each case

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change the switch in the `onClick` to :

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Pdf_Activity.class);
switch (v.getId())
{
    case R.id.btn1:
        i.putExtra("file",1);
            startActivity(i);
        break;
    case R.id.btn2:
        i.putExtra("file",2);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    case R.id.btn3:
        i.putExtra("file",3);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    case R.id.btn4:
        i.putExtra("file",4);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    case R.id.btn5:
        i.putExtra("file",5);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
        default:
            break;
}
```

Then in the `pdf_activity` Use it like so:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
int x = bundle.getInt("file");

switch (x)
{
...
}
```

Comment: "application has stopped " !
wich code i use to open pdf file in pdf_activity 
switch (x)
{
.......................
}

Comment: thank you very much Derek ,
Now I fixed the code but there is one problem :only the first book opened and the others books no

Comment: Add a breakpoint on the `switch(x)` to see what the value contains when you press the other buttons besides the first book

Comment: I think the problem is in the XML file of pdf files
       <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
<com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
            android:id="@+id/pdf"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
       
    </LinearLayout>

Comment: @walidroid why are you using so many PDFViews? I think you should just have one and display it only once

Comment: thank you Derek ;) yes why I used many pdfViews hhhh now it works fine
i really appreciate your help THANKS

Comment: @walidroid if my answer fixed your issue, please mark it as correct to close the question. Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the XML file of pdf files

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
<com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
            android:id="@+id/pdf1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
            android:id="@+id/pdf2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
            android:id="@+id/pdf3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
.......................
....................
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```